# How to copy paste a lot of html who is shortly (img01, img02, img03,...) different?

Tags: repeat

I have 300 img to put in my html code but I don't know how to do it quickly.
This is my code :

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="images/image01.jpg" />
<img class="img-responsive" src="images/image02.jpg" />
<img class="img-responsive" src="images/image03.jpg" />
```

I would like to copy paste it 300 times but I don't want to write 01, 02, 03, 04,... manually.
Do you know a way to do it ?

Thank you :)

Comment: Step 1: Pick a programming language.

Comment: I don't know anything about programming language. Can I do it in js or php ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<body onload="myFunction()">
<div id="images">
<div>
</body>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  for(let id=1; id<=300; id++){
    document.querySelector('#images').innerHTML += `<img class="img-responsive" src="images/image${String(id).padStart(2, '0')}.jpg" />`
  }
}
</script>
```

you can use javascript to do this activity

Comment: I had to add function before MyFunction and it's working. 
Thank you for your help :)

Comment: This is not an elegant solution since it will update the dom 300 times. Instead create an array and insert that

Answer (score -1):

using for a for-loop

```
<?php
    foreach(range(1,300) as $num){          
        echo "<img class='img-responsive' src='images/image"+str_pad($num, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);+".jpg'/>";
    }    
?>
```